# Struts 2 <s:select> filling other fields within a form

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

Whenever I select a value from my `<s:select />` drop down box it fills the rest of the values within that table of my <`s:form>`. The list I'm using is a placeholder but shouldn't be effecting that.
Additionally this only occurs whenever I change it from the default

Table Code:

```
<table id="pricingInput" class="footable" style="width: 700px; table-layout: fixed; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 25px; float:right; margin-bottom:50px;">
    <thead><tr><th style="text-align: center;">Account Name</th><th style="text-align: center;">Annual kWh Volume</th><th style="text-align: center">Rate Class</th><th style="text-align: center;">Add Another?</th></tr></thead>
    <tr>
        <td><s:textfield name="nameHolder" /></td>
        <td><s:textfield name="volumeHolder" /></td>
        <td><s:select headerValue="Choose Rate Class" name="rateClass" list="months" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="addButton" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">
        </td>
    </tr>                                   
</table>
```

[image: Image of issue]

So the overall question is what could be causing this behavior? Then how do I go about rectifying this or preventing it? Since I've never run into this before with any of my other struts projects I'm not sure where to start and Google wasn't much help.

Edit:

JavaScript for adding/deleting rows(disclaimer it's probably more complex then I need I found it on a site and was a bit confused on this topic):

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function addRow(){
            $("#pricingInput").on('click', 'input.addButton', function() {
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
                var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
                var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
                $clone.find('td').each(function(){
                    var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
                    var id = el.attr('id') || null;
                    if(id) {

                        i = id.substr(id.length-1);
                       var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
                       var splitString = prefix.split("[");
                        prefix = splitString[0];
                        if(splitString[1] != null){
                            var splitStringAgain = splitString[1].split("");
                            prefix = prefix+(i+1)+splitStringAgain[1];
                        }
                        else
                           prefix = prefix+"[" + (i+1) + "]";
                        //el.attr('id', prefix);
                        //el.attr('name', '['+(i+1)+']');
                        prefix=undefined;
                        splitString=undefined;
                    }
                });
                $clone.find('input:text').val('');
                $tr.closest('table').append($clone);
            });

            $("#pricingInput").on('change', 'select', function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val(val);
            });
        });

        </script>
        <script>
            function deleteRow(r)
            {
            var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("pricingInput").deleteRow(i);
            }
        </script>
```

Page Load Code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public String execute(){
    months = new ArrayList<String>();
    years = new ArrayList<String>();
    months.add("01");
    months.add("02");
    months.add("03");
    months.add("04");
    months.add("05");
    months.add("06");
    months.add("07");
    months.add("08");
    months.add("09");
    months.add("10");
    months.add("11");
    months.add("12");
    years.add("2014");
    years.add("2015");
    years.add("2016");
    years.add("2017");
    years.add("2018");
    years.add("2019");
    years.add("2020");



    utility_map.put("DUQ", rate_class_duq);
    utility_map.put("Met_Ed", rate_clas_met_ed);
    utility_map.put("Penn_Power", rate_class_pp);
    utility_map.put("PPL", rate_class_ppl);
    utility_map.put("Penelec", rate_class_penelec);
    utility_map.put("Penn_Power", rate_class_pp);
    utility_map.put("WPP", rate_class_wpp);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Form Submission Code:

```
    @Override
public String execute() {

    try{
        nameList = Arrays.asList(nameHolder.split(","));
        volumeList = Arrays.asList(volumeHolder.split(","));
        for(int x = 0; x<nameList.size(); x++){
            Pricing holder = new Pricing();
        try{
            if(nameList.get(x) != null && volumeList.get(x) != null){
                if(volumeList.get(x).isEmpty() != true && nameList.get(x).isEmpty() != true){
                    holder.setName(nameList.get(x));
                    holder.setVolume(Double.valueOf(volumeList.get(x)));
                    pricing.add(holder);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( writer );
            e.printStackTrace( printWriter );
            printWriter.flush();

            String stackTrace = writer.toString();
            System.out.print(stackTrace);
        }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e ){
        addActionError("An unknown error occured.  Plase try reloading the page.");
        return ERROR;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you post the code that makes changes to textfields?

Comment: No java code is run during the changes to the textfields which is the part that I find confusing. A default page loading action is run when the page is loaded then the submit button runs a submission action. However neither of those have anything to do with the population of the textfields @RomanC

Comment: What java code is run?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript that is running when the value of the selects change?  Your screenshot suggests that there is some kind of loop on the JSP that you didn't provide in your code snippet too (the screenshot shows four rows in the table but the code snippet suggests only one row.  A wild guess: you might be reusing names or ids on your fields when they need to be unique.

Comment: @ErikGillespie I added the javascript to the post I didn't think of looking there though I'll delve into that code

Comment: @RomanC I added the Java code to both sides of the page both page load and form submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the event handler you are adding to each select's onChange may be the culprit:

```
$("#pricingInput").on('change', 'select', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val(val);
});
```

When a <select> changes, you are finding all of the <input type="text"> tags inside the nearest <tr> to the <select> that changed and setting the value of each of those text inputs to the value of the <select>.

Get rid of that event handler and your problem should go away.